# R shiny custom function

Tags: r, shiny

I'm trying to call a reactive function within my custom function and I couldn't. What is the best way to do this, here is the simplified code and I can't pass everything as a functional parameter because there will be too many to pass.

```
  library(shiny); 
  myf<-function(){ return(psd()$y) }
  shinyApp( ui = textOutput("test2"), 
      server = function(input, output) {
          psd<-reactive({ return(data.frame(x=10,y=30)) })
          output$test2 <- renderText({ myf() })
        }
      )
```

This code generates an error : `Error in myf() : could not find function "psd"`
What is the best way to call custom function which utilizes other function from within shinyserver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends if you want your function to be reactive as well or not.

In the case of reactivity use:

```
myf <- reactive({return(psd()$y})
```

If you don't want it to be reactive use

```
 myf <- function() {return(isolate(psd$y))}
```

---

Your reactive expression does not have a reactive Value (like input$). Therefore it does not get created. To understand reactivity better read [this awesome instruction](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/reactivity-overview.html).

---

Furthermore maybe you try to avoid hardcoding and try to add the reactive function you want to call as a parameter in your function, like this:

`myf<-function(func){ return(func()$y) }`

And then:

`output$test2 <- renderText({ myf(psd) })`

Comment: As I mentioned, the code I entered is very simplified. I cannot pass `psd` to my function, because, it's not just `psd` there are lot of other values that I need to pass and is not practical to pass all of them. I'm looking for a way to call a reactive function in my custom function !

Comment: Well, in the Code you provided the reactive function is not reactive, and that might be the issue. In your real code, did you ensure reactivity?

Comment: Edited answer, does it help now?

Comment: Interesting, If I move the function in to shinyServer function as reactive expression then it can access all other functions. To give more details I'm calling a lapply function like this : `lapply(c("a","b","c",myf)` so, in case of making `myf` reactive how do I access "a", "b","c" within the reactive function?

Comment: I don't see why they have to be reactive in the same `lapply`. What do you want to achieve on high level?

Comment: Never mind, I moved `myf` inside shinyServer function and it worked well, I have other questions but I will create a new track